# Trying to get a json result back from method in another namespace, having issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a seperate .js file and namespace for json requests.
I have another .js file and namespace for the actual logic.

I can't seem to get the result back in my logic layer.

```
var jsonResult = Blah.Data.LoadAggregates();

alert(jsonResult);
alert(jsonResult.d.length);
alert(jsonResult.length);
```

**all of the above calls are returning undefined.**

```
Blah.RegisterNamespace("Blah.Data");

(function(Data) {


    Data.LoadAggregates = function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "asdf.asmx/GetAggregates",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                ???????

            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("error" + msg);
            }
        });

    };

})(Blah.Data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning that the `$.ajax` call will not wait for the server to respond.

Therefore, your `LoadAggregates` function finishes executing *before* the server replies.

In order to get the server's response, your `LoadAggregates` function needs to take a callback parameter, the way `$.ajax` does.

For example:

```
Data.LoadAggregates = function(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "asdf.asmx/GetAggregates",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //Do something to the data if you want to

            callback(data);        //You can pass any parameters you want
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert("error" + msg);
        }
    });

};
```

You would then call it like this:

```
Blah.Data.LoadAggregates(function(jsonResult) {
    alert(jsonResult.length);
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I had a feeling it had to do with timing :)